# how can I split the screen into two screens and make Gdx.input.setInputProcessor () accept two processors?

Tags: libgdx

I want to draw in the first screen portion, and manipulate the buttons in the second part.

This is what I tried:

if (mouse.x <600) {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor (new InputProcessor () {

```
Override
public boolean touchup (int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
return false;
}
.
.
.
.
.
}
if (mouse.x> = 600) {
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor (stage);
}
```

the problem is that I have the ability to go from the first part to the second but I'm not allowed to go from the second to the first, it blocks the mouse coordinates in x = 600 This is what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do it like that. Use scene2d for your buttons and menus and use InputMultiplexer to set up multiple input processor.